# angular-ui-bootstrap 0.13.4 tooltip with custom toggle not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

To make bootstrap's tooltips / popover closable via custom code we are using a directive:

```
.directive('popoverToogle', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      function trigger(element, evt) {
        evt = new Event(evt);
        element[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
      }
      scope.opened = false;
      scope.togglePopover = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          trigger(element, scope.opened ? 'close' : 'open');
          scope.opened = !scope.opened;
        });
      };
      scope.closePopover = function() {
        $timeout(function(){
          trigger(element, 'close');
          scope.opened = false;
        });
      };
      return element[0].addEventListener('click', scope.togglePopover);
    }
  };
```

It uses the `dispatcheEvent(new Event())` method as mentioned in the [Changelog](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for version 0.13.4 .
As it has to be expected this code is not working in Internet Explorers.

What I am wondering is:
<strike>Why do the tests pass?</strike>
Looking at the [commit](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/7556beda486f26b40fb860448316e8a32457e9e9) they use the exact same code as my directive.

What can I do to make my directive work also?

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended with up a polyfill borrowed from [here](https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-service/tree/master/polyfills/Event). Most others I found weren't correct in that way that they assumed `typeof window.CustomEvent === 'function'` or `typeof window.CustomEvent === 'object'`.
This doesn't address Safari where `window.CustomEvent` **is** an object but behaves like a constructor.
So

`try {
  var ev = new Event('click');
  catch (e) {
   …
  }`

appeared the correct solution for me.

Still considering to change to angularStrap.